# How to Sync Data to Server from a Flutter Windows App Even When the App is Closed?

Tags: flutter, windows, background-process

I’m developing a **Flutter application for Windows Desktop** and I’ve encountered a problem. I need my **app to sync data to the server even when the app is closed**. This is crucial for my application as it needs to maintain up-to-date data on the server at all times.

I’ve been searching for a solution but haven’t found a suitable one yet. Is there a specific package or technique that could help me achieve this functionality? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

I’ve tried using the **`connectivity_plus`** package, but it doesn’t seem to provide the functionality I need when the app is closed.

Comment: I think we have to take a closer look into the Window API. I suggest using `win32` plugin to make the development process easier.

Comment: I have asked ChatGPT. Here, it's answer: https://chat.openai.com/c/0dc705a7-f2c5-4321-b70d-462a037b3356. Then, I will convert the c++ code to dart code. It'll be tricky because I'm developing this feature and this video may help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pY-oRxRZO7Q&t=2228s.

Comment: Maybe it's not the quickest solution, but it's possible to develop a Windows service in Flutter. The service would keep the data updated, while the application you already have could act only as a GUI for the data. 
I can post an answer if you're interested.

Comment: @il_boga, if you could do it, it would be a great help as I am a mobile developer struggling with Windows APIs. I have also explored docs and came to the conclusion we have to develop a native Windows service for this. maybe there is a way to do it with Flutter that I don't know about yet.

Comment: @HoangTrungNguyen thank you for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe we should, create a Dart plugin for handling background service using `win32`. In the Flutter code of your main app, we will create a method channel to call to the C++ code, which is generated in the Dart plugin for background service.

Comment: I think the most difficult task is understanding how the `win32` plugin works. Here, we have to deeply understand about operating system. 'Cause, the plugin requires us to allocate memory for variables, then free up the memory after used.

Answer (score 0):

So, as requested, here's how I created a Windows service written in Flutter/Dart. Mostly, I used [NSSM](http://nssm.cc) to wrap my Flutter-Windows app, because, on Flutter part, you can pretty much write your app as usual. The only thing to look out for is the lack of a GUI: since it's a service in background, you probably don't want a window visible on the desktop.
This is MyApp class:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ini_cfg.Config ini;
  const MyApp(this.ini, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      home: SizedBox(width: 1, height: 1, child: Container(color: Colors.transparent)),
    );
  }
}
```

I could not use the usual `bitsdojo_window` package because there was some issue at the time with its `hide` method (I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/bitsdojo/bitsdojo_window/issues/221), but it's still pending), so I had to resort to work around it by creating a GUI of 1x1 transparent pixel. For some reasons that I have not investigated, when running the service from Android Studio, you still get a blacked-out window as a GUI: this does not happen with the final exe file.

The service job is done directly in the `main` method: in my case, I set up a [cron](https://pub.dev/packages/cron) job to run some methods at different time of the day, but you could simply set up one or more `Timer`s to synchronize the data as frequently as you need.
Once the code is ready, you just need to build the app as normal Windows application (just check the Flutter tutorial on how to do it), then follow the NSSM instructions to wrap your app and make it run as a service: the simplest way to do it is to run `nssm install "My service" your_flutter.exe -s` from the command line, on a folder where you have both nssm.exe and the Flutter exe file. I made a .bat file to handle the service installation, here it is:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Installing service...
SET serviceName="My custom service"

nssm status %serviceName% 

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    echo Service already installed
    nssm restart %serviceName%
    echo ERR: %errorlevel%
    if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
        echo Can't restart the service. Try manually or reboot.
        PAUSE
        EXIT /B 0
    )
    PAUSE
    EXIT /B 0
)

nssm install %serviceName% your_flutter.exe -s
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    ECHO Installation failed
    PAUSE
    EXIT /B -1
)
ECHO Service installed

nssm set %serviceName% AppDirectory "%cd%"
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    ECHO Can't set execution folder
    PAUSE
    EXIT /B -2
)

nssm set %serviceName% Description "My custom service description"

nssm set %serviceName% Start SERVICE_AUTO_START
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    ECHO Can't set autostart
    PAUSE
    EXIT  /B -3
)

nssm set %serviceName% AppStdOut "%cd%\service.log"
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    ECHO Can't set log file for stdout
    PAUSE
    EXIT  /B -10
)

nssm set %serviceName% AppStdErr "%cd%\service.log"
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    ECHO Can't set log file for stderr
    PAUSE
    EXIT  /B -11
)

nssm start %serviceName%
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    ECHO Can't start the service
    PAUSE
    EXIT  /B -100
)

ECHO Successfully completed
PAUSE
EXIT /B 0
```